# How can I remove the Plans option from my Azure Boards Menu?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I have a menu option for both Delivery Plans and Plans on my Boards Menu.  I belive that Plans may have neen and  old name to the Delivery Plans feature. When I click Plans I get the never ending spinning Loading so I would like to remove this non-working item.

When I open extension I only see Delivey Plans so I can't see a way to uninstall this via an extension.  How can I correct this?

[image]

I have reviwed extensions and don't see an option to remove it.

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer can give you some help

Answer (score 1):

Now, the Delivey Plans is built in feature in Azure DevOps. We don't need to install extensions to achieve it. Refer to this doc: [Delivery Plans 2.0 general availability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/sprint-187-update)

To remove the Plan option in Boards Tab, you can navigate to **Organization Settings -> Extensions** and find the **Delivery Plans** extension.

Then you can try to uninstall it.

For example:

[image]

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Uninstall or disable an extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/marketplace/install-extension?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#uninstall-or-disable-an-extension)

**Note:** If you don't have permission to uninstall the extension, you may need to contact the Project Collection Admin to uninstall it.